# Emrlapply of segue package doesn't work on simple task

Tags: r, emr

I tried to reproduce simple example of using `segue` from https://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/segue-r-to-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-hadoop/

Cluster creation was successful

```
> cl <- createCluster(numInstances=2)
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:02:08
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:02:39
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:03:10
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:03:42
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:04:13
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:04:44
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:05:15
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:05:46
STARTING - 2012-05-27 14:06:17
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2012-05-27 14:06:48
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2012-05-27 14:07:19
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2012-05-27 14:07:50
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2012-05-27 14:08:21
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2012-05-27 14:08:52
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2012-05-27 14:09:23
BOOTSTRAPPING - 2012-05-27 14:09:55
WAITING - 2012-05-27 14:10:26
Your Amazon EMR Hadoop Cluster is ready for action. 
Remember to terminate your cluster with stopCluster().
Amazon is billing you!
```

Local simulation was OK, but running it on the cluster returned an error each time.

```
> myList <- NULL
> set.seed(1)
> for (i in 1:10){
  +   a <- c(rnorm(999), NA)
  +   myList[[i]] <- a
  + }
> outputLocal  <- lapply(myList, mean, na.rm=T)
> outputEmr   <- emrlapply(cl, myList, mean,  na.rm=T)
RUNNING - 2012-05-27 14:11:58
RUNNING - 2012-05-27 14:12:29
RUNNING - 2012-05-27 14:13:00
WAITING - 2012-05-27 14:13:31
Error in lines[[i]] : subgroup is out of range
> stopCluster(cl)
```

I like the idea of this package and I hope it will be useful in my work, but I cannot figure out how to solve this basic problem.

Version of `segue` 0.02

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

**UPDATE**: I tried to run another example test case of Pi estimation, and `emrlapply` returned the same error message.

**UPDATE2**:
I updated to version 0.03 and now I could not connect to cluster. After successful start instances were tried to shut down with no effect. I terminated instances via AWS consol. So the old problem was solved but the new one appeared.

```
> cl <- createCluster(numInstances=2)
STARTING - 2012-06-01 22:36:10
STARTING - 2012-06-01 22:36:41
STARTING - 2012-06-01 22:37:12
STARTING - 2012-06-01 22:37:43
STARTING - 2012-06-01 22:38:14
STARTING - 2012-06-01 22:38:46
SHUTTING_DOWN - 2012-06-01 22:39:17
SHUTTING_DOWN - 2012-06-01 22:39:48
...
SHUTTING_DOWN - 2012-06-01 22:48:05
SHUTTING_DOWN - 2012-06-01 22:48:36
FAILED - 2012-06-01 22:49:07
>
```

Comment: well the "good" news is that I can reproduce your error. I'm debugging now to see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @JDLong, thank you for your response! That's strange that someone else didn't find this issue previously.

Comment: i think something changed recently. I've traced it back to the latest R version not loading properly. Only I'm not sure why.

Comment: I just pushed version 0.04 out. Give it a go and let me know if that fixes it. I found a few things that might be the problem.

Comment: +100! Thank you very much for your help! Last version works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Amazon changed the EMR service to default to
the 1.0 version of the EMR AMI if no specific version was called.
Since Jan 1, the behavior had been to default to the latest version.
When I made the changes to default to a recent version I then had
issues with the current incarnation of Hadoop wanting output to be put
in a sub-bucket on S3.

I had to upgrade the Java AWS API code to the latest version in order to make these changes.

New version of the tar ball is here:
http://code.google.com/p/segue/downloads/list
or you can clone the source and build it yourself, if you're into that
sort of thing.

I've indexed Segue to 0.03 with this change.

EDIT: I just found that m1.small is a problem (32 bit) so I've changed the default and changed behavior to not let users specify m1.small. New version is 0.04.

Comment: thank you for your help and sorry for my delayed response, I had a bad connection to internet and thought that it was a reason of problems with new version of `segue`, but unfortunately stable connection disn't solve the problem. See please my updated question.

Comment: well that's really odd. The behavior where it starts up and then immediately fails is indicative of an error in the boot up script. Can you tell me which size instance you were trying to start? That will help me with debugging.

Comment: I have used default types of master and slave instances m1.small

Comment: I know this is an old question, but, I'm having the same issue, using version 0.05 with all defaults. Is this just an intermittent problem?